# Wordpress duplicatie child category slug

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm having trouble with my child category slugs in Wordpress.
I want the same slug for the child category with different parent categories.

**For example**

*Brand / Shirts*

**changes to**

*Brand / Shirts-2*

I'm not using WooCommerce it's just for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, all category slugs are stored in the database as unique, non-hierarchical entries. They can not share a slug.

Maybe it would be feasible for you to register custom post types, each with its own custom taxonomy (category), as a workaround?

You should be able to do...

`/post-type/post-type-category`

`/another-type/another-type-category`

Which would look the way you want it to look.